# P/Invoke c# and native c++

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-c++, native-code

My c# is really bad, and I'll get a book or something to improve it later on. Right now, I have a gui in c# wpf and a dll library in native c++. All the tutorials I see on the internet for p/invoke don't have classes in them.

Here's what my code looks like in c++:

```
//Dostuff.h

class foo {
__declspec(dllexport) void dostuff();
 }
```

How would I go about calling the dll from c#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not seeing classes is no accident.  You cannot pinvoke this method, you'd first have to create an instance of the native foo class.  Which you cannot do with pinvoke.  It must be a static method.

Comment: Can't you pinvoke `CoCreateInstance` or `CoGetClassObject`? And call the method with `DispInvoke`?

Comment: @Motes: `CoCreateInstance`, `CoGetClassObject`, and `DispInvoke` are COM-related stuff.  Unless the code was built with COM in mind, or someone's willing to retrofit a COM interface onto it, they won't help much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947870/convert-c-dll-project-to-com-dll-project

Comment: Thanks @cHao, that was a newb mistake, I guess if he had a COM DLL he could just add a reference to it. I never have actually done anything with a C++ DLL. That is, except for COM, so I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ library without wrappers is often useless outside of the C++ compiler that built it.  C# won't make using such a library easy for you...and even if you manage to do it, things may break in all kinds of interesting ways.

You have two relatively safe choices, though:

- Export a set of `extern "C"` wrapper functions in your library.  You'd take a pointer to the object you want to use, and call a function on that object.  If you go that route, it's about as close as you can get to universally compatible; any language that can call C functions will be able to use the library.
- If you're using Visual C++, you can do something similar specifically for .net.  Write a wrapper in C++/CLI that compiles for .net, but forwards calls to the native library.